# TSLint how to allow URL for comment-format rule?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I am using TypeScript and React and TSLint with comment-format rule.

- https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/comment-format/

now I got a weird warning that the comment-format rule doesn't allow URL in the JSX.

sample code here:

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.jp">https://www.google.co.jp</a>
```

warning here:

```
comment must start with a space
```

tslint.json here:

```
{
  "extends": ["tslint:latest", "tslint-react"],
  "rules": {}
}
```

packages:

- "typescript": "^1.8.10"
- "tslint": "^3.15.1"
- "tslint-react": "^1.0.0"

Anyone know any workaround for that?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is that it thinks that your url is a comment (cos of the double slash). You should try and find rules that allow for JSX

Comment: yes, that is true. so I tried to ask if anyone has a nicer idea.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by using flag. 
but I am not sure if it is the best way, though.

```
{/* tslint:disable: comment-format */}
<a href="https://www.google.co.jp">https://www.google.co.jp</a>
{/* tslint:enable: comment-format */}
```